# How does serializer retrieve columns referred by a reverse foreign key?

Tags: python, django

In a scenario of transaction processing, we have:

- table `order` to record incoming transactions, and
- table `order_log` to log updates on a recorded order, with a foreign key to table `order`.

A recorded order may have zero to multiple updates on the log.

We want to make a flattened view of the two tables like a SQL query selecting from `order left outer join order_log`, with the following behaviour:

- if the order has no update, list the order in joint with null values;
- if the order has one update, list the order in joint with the update log;
- if the order has multiple updates, list the order multiple times in joint with each update log.

As the sample source code below, we used `.prefetch_related('orderlog_set')`, and it gets the wanted flattening effect, and the Django backend log shows a left-outer-join SQL query sent to the database as expected. So, the mutual relation works correctly for all the three conditions above.

**However, we cannot retrieve columns in `order_item`, as the table is in a foreign key's reverse direction.**

The serializer `FlatOrderLogSerializer` bases its meta-model on the table `order`, so it refers to table `order_log` by a foreign key's reverse or backward direction. As a result, the serializer cannot retrieve the correct column and always gets null values.

We correctly retrieved columns in the native table and tables referred by a foreign key's normal direction. Unfortunately, just the reverse/backward foreign key does not work.

We are new to this part of Django and not sure how to correctly set the `source` attribute of the field object. We tried `serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='orderlog_set__update_ts', ...` and a few other options, but not working so far. See the comments in the sample code for more details.

Just let me know if you need more information, and any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
# Table 'order'
class Order(models.Model):
    ...

# Table 'order_log'
class OrderLog(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order')
    update_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="Last Updated On")
    ...

# The serializer
class FlatOrderLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Standing at table 'order', it refers to table 'order_log' by a reverse (backward) foreign-key.
    # The field with source='orderlog_set__update_ts' always gets null, and
    # we tried other source settings, e.g. 'orderlog_set.update_ts', or 'orderlog.update_ts', 
    # unfortunately nothing works so far.
    update_ts = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='orderlog_set__update_ts', allow_null=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'update_ts',
            ...
        )

# The view
class FlatOrderLogView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = rest_models.FlatOrderLogSerializer
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        flat_orderlogs = Order.active_objects.filter(
            ...
        ).prefetch_related(
            'orderlog_set',
        ).all()
        return flat_orderlogs
```

Comment: Is changing to a nested serializer instead of this flat repeating one an option? Would simplify everything quite a bit

Comment: Nested serializers will work for sure, but it means we need to fight back the requirement. I am reading [this post](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4929#issuecomment-283066524), and it seems promising. Not sure whether it is also a nested serializer, though.

Comment: @Mike is there any problem in using serializermethodfield instead for the **update_ts** ?

Comment: Thank you for your input, @quickhaze. Unfortunately, I just tried `SerializerMethodField`, which didn't work for me either. In the experiment, `.prefetch_related()` correctly invoked the queryset as `left outer join`. However, the instances contain a null object for the member of `orderlog_set`, so the `get_update_ts()` function doesn't have a reference still. Not sure if I did something wrong. Or, maybe Django does not support foreign keys in the reverse direction very well.

Answer (score 0):

After some Google searching, it looks like:

- The Django framework provides a standard function `select_related()` for joining following a foreign key’s forward direction. The backend implements this function as an inner-join SQL query.
- However, we did not find an elegant way to look backward by an outer-join. Instead, most articles recommend using function  `prefetch_related()` and making a nested serializer. And this design pattern seems to be a common practice.

**Below are some tentative thoughts, and we hope to get feedback or corrections from experts:**

With SQL query, we can refer to another table in the foreign key's backward direction by an outer-join. However, it seems that Django does not encourage this intuitive design pattern, therefore, did not implement a standard method. If confirmed, we will give up the outer-join query and look into other solutions instead.